# Laravel 8.0 pagination() shows "previous" & "Next" instead of page numbers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

In my local environment pagination works perfectly fine it shows page numbers and I'm using tailwind
but when I deploy my app on Heroku, pagination shows the "previous" & "next" buttons only even though I'm not using simplePagination and I'm not sure why. Here is what I tried to do to fix it :

- I made sure that the page links where generated using https.
- I used a custom view "view/vendor/tailwind.blade.php"

Comment: Please provide code example of your pagination view so we know what's wrong with it [ask]